# setting an array of text into an array of textview

Tags: android

i faced this problem when trying to assign a character into an array of text view

counter is a count which i got from reading the number of characters i have in a text file

```
            TextView[] tv = new TextView[counter];

        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        {
            tv[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
            tv[i].setText(singleText[i]); 
            setContentView(tv[i]); 
        }
```

after this, when i try to run the application i the application just force closes.. i have no idea on how to debug it

my application would need to set 1 character into 1 text view

Comment: First step would be to send us the log output, which should have detailed information about the problem.

Comment: hey mike, the other bros helped me with the code already i shall try their methods... if it still doesn't work i will post the logs here thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't initialized the TextViews properly. That's why you are getting nullpointerexception. You have to initialize the TextView as follows:

```
tv[i] = new TextView(this);
```

Here this is the your Activity instance.

And there is a problem in your

```
setContentView(tv[i]);
```

If you use this code then in the screen you will see only the last textview.

To see all the TextView you have to add all the TextView in a container like LinearLayout. Then you have set the container as content View.

Here is the code you can use:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,              
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
TextView[] tv = new TextView[counter];

for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
{
        tv[i] = new TextView(this);
        tv[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,              
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
        tv[i].setText(singleText[i]); 
        linearLayout.addView(tv[i]); 
}
setContentView(linearLayout);
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: @benjamin: is singleText a character array?

Comment: @gypsicoder i got an error saying resources not found exception

Comment: i think you got it because of the character array. just change this line tv[i].setText(singleText[i]); to tv[i].setText(""+singleText[i]);

Comment: hey @gypsicoder the code works however i am facing a problem where if i have a few words the words would not overflow to the next line in the textview they would extend all the way out of screen

Comment: you can set singeLine attribute true for the TextViews

Comment: hmm cant seem to work the text still goes way off screen.. maybe it is because each of the text is on 1 textview by itself so even setting a singleline attribute it still overflows

Answer (score 1):

TextView[] tv = new TextView[counter];
Here you creating array filled with null references. Of course it will crash here tv[i].setLayoutParams() with null pointer exception

Comment: Actually this code is completely wrong. You should define some kind of layout in .xml and then add you TextViews in that layout

Comment: i would need to make x number of textviews depending on how many character i have